# How do I return details about a geojson polygon on click in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am drawing a geojson of census places into a Leaflet map. When a polygon is clicked I want details about that polygon returned, for example the name, GEOID, population, etc. The details in the geojson object.

Right now I'm just starting with feeding that into the console, but eventually I want to send those off to other functions. How do I find that information on click?

Here is how I'm drawing the geojson and adding the click event listener:

```
   L.geoJson( mapData )
    .on('click', function(e){
        console.log(_clicked polygon details here_);
    })
    .addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This returns the feature information I was looking for:

```
L.geoJson(mapData)
    .on('click', function(e){
        console.log(e.sourceTarget.feature);
    })
    .addTo(map)
```